# VBA: Use text in column to replace the same text in the same column

Tags: vba, excel, replace, str-replace

I am trying to replace all text in column T13 to T-lastrow.

Since I already have and will receive more text in the T-column (dynamic sheet that will get imported data from another sheet).
Basically, I want the text that is in T to be put into this:
`{Nyckelord="TEXT HERE";}`

However, my macro go into an infinite loop (I think).
Is it also possible to automatically remove any commas that might be between words in column T?
Example:
Text in Column T13+:
Icecream, waffle
It should be `{Nyckelord="Icecream waffle";}`

```
Sub SearchTerms()

Dim Findtext As String
Dim Replacetext As String
Dim LastRowInput As Long
Dim field1 As String

LastRowInput = Cells(Rows.count, "T").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To LastRowInput

field1 = Range("T13" & i).Value

Findtext = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("T13").Value
field1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("T" & LastRowInput + 1).Value

Replacetext = "{Nyckelord=""" & field1 & """;}"

Sheets("Sheet1").Select

Cells.Replace What:=Findtext, Replacement:=Replacetext, LookAt:=xlPart, _
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
ReplaceFormat:=False

Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
field1 = Range("T13" & i).Value
```

This line is going to start reading at cell T132. Do you mean this?

```
field1 = Range("T" & 13 + i).value
```

In which case surely the loop should be:

```
For i = 0 to LastRowInput - 13
```

Also, if you just want to wrap the contents of each cell in "T" with the  `{Nyckelord="TEXT HERE";}` syntax, why not just do it this way?

```
    LastRowInput= Range("T" & ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1).End(xlUp).Row 

    For i = 0 to LastRowInput - 13

       Range("T" & 13 + i).Value = "{Nyckelord=" & Range("T" & 13 + i).Value & ";}"

    Next i
```

Comment: Hi @StefJoynson Thank you for your reply. It is almost working just to use the Loop you wrote, however, it seems like it is not stopping at the end of the last row. It fills from T13:T.

Comment: Where is it stopping? If it is one row too low just amend the -13 to -14 and you're sorted. Otherwise, the problem may be with the way you have calculated LastRowInput.

Comment: Well it fills the complete T row. So at some thousands.

Comment: It's your LastRowsCount calculation. I will edit my answer to correct for you.

Comment: I tried to use your new loop, but it is still not working. Nothing happens? No errors, however, no output either

Comment: When you step through it what value is assigned to LastInputRow?

Comment: ahh mate, it is working. LastRowInput was RowLastInput

Comment: Thank you :) Could you please change the LastInputRow so it matches, just for other people´s sake.